# Accessing global class variable modified inside TimerTask()

Tags: java, android, timertask

How do I access class variable that is modified inside a TimerTask(). Here's an example:

```
public class Foo{
    
    // Global variables
    private int count = 0;
    private Timer fooTimer;

    public void startTimerTask(){
      TimerTask fooTimerTask = new TimerTask(){
       int c = 0;
       public void run(){
         c = count;                     // Using count here and updating its value
         c++;                           // Local counter is incremented here
         count = c;                     // Reassigning count
         System.out.println(count);     // Prints updated value
       }
      }
      fooTimer.schedueleAtFixedRate(fooTimerTask, 0, 2000);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
      // Start new timer and start tasks
      fooTimer = new Timer();
      startTimerTask();

      // Trying to check value of count outside TimerTask()
      count = count + 5;
      System.out.println("Count: "+count)         // Count returns 5  
    }

}
```

Using the above example, I would like to figure out how I can access modified value of count from TimerTask() and modify it in main() so that it also reflects on count used in TimerTask().

I understand that Java creates a copy of the original count and passes that copy to the TimerTask (which is an anonymous inner class) to be used upon.

But is there a way to use count as a shared resource?

I have also tried using single-element int array instead of int variable as count. But it still shows the same result.

Answer (score 0):

This topic has been addressed many times on Stack Overflow, apparently a common schoolwork assignment. So I'll be brief. Search Stack Overflow to learn more.

## `AtomicInteger`

> But is there a way to use count as a shared resource?

Yes. Make the shared count an [`AtomicInteger`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html).

Also, the `Timer`/`TimerTask` classes were supplanted many years ago by the Executors framework added to Java 5, as noted in their Javadoc.

By the way, watch your naming. Class names start with uppercase letter in Java, by convention.

By the way, your `// Global variables` label is a misnomer. What you are labeling are commonly called "member fields" or "instance variables". Closer to a true “global variable” in Java would be a `static` variable.

```java
package work.basil.demo;

import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

public class Foo{

    // Member field variables
    public AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger( 0 ) ;
}
```

Do your tasks in background threads.

You can define your [`Runnable`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Runnable.html)/`Callable` using either lambda syntax or conventional syntax.

Obtain a scheduled executor service from [`Executors`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html).

Notice that the `main` thread accesses the `counter` to obtain its current value while the background thread may be modifying that value. The `AtomicInteger` class makes thread-safe our threaded calls to [`get`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html#get()) and [`updateAndGet`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html#updateAndGet(java.util.function.IntUnaryOperator)).

```java
package work.basil.demo;

import java.time.Duration;
import java.time.Instant;
import java.util.concurrent.*;
import java.util.function.IntUnaryOperator;

public class FooApp
{
    public static void main ( String[] args )
    {
        System.out.println( "Our demo's `main` method is starting. " + Instant.now() );

        Foo foo = new Foo();
        IntUnaryOperator unaryOperator = ( int x ) -> ( x + 5 );
        Runnable task = ( ) -> {
            int newCount = foo.counter.updateAndGet( unaryOperator );
            System.out.println( "New count is " + newCount + " at approximately " + Instant.now() );  // Beware: These calls may *not* appear on console in expected sequence.
        };
        ScheduledExecutorService ses = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
        ScheduledFuture < ? > sf = ses.scheduleAtFixedRate( task , 0 , 2 , TimeUnit.SECONDS );

        // Let our background task run a few times.
        // Check the current value once in a while.
        for ( int i = 0 ; i < 3 ; i++ )
        {
            try { Thread.sleep( Duration.ofSeconds( 5 ).toMillis() ); } catch ( InterruptedException e ) { e.printStackTrace(); }
            System.out.println( "Main thread reports counter is " + foo.counter.get() + " at " + Instant.now() );
        }
        try { Thread.sleep( Duration.ofSeconds( 20 ).toMillis() ); } catch ( InterruptedException e ) { e.printStackTrace(); }
        ses.shutdown();
        try { ses.awaitTermination( 1 , TimeUnit.MINUTES ); } catch ( InterruptedException e ) { e.printStackTrace(); }
        System.out.println( "Our demo's `main` method is ending. " + Instant.now() );
    }
}
```

When run.

```
Our demo's `main` method is starting. 2021-06-17T22:02:47.679682Z
New count is 5 at approximately 2021-06-17T22:02:47.692962Z
New count is 10 at approximately 2021-06-17T22:02:49.696992Z
New count is 15 at approximately 2021-06-17T22:02:51.696261Z
Main thread reports counter is 15 at 2021-06-17T22:02:52.697280Z
New count is 20 at approximately 2021-06-17T22:02:53.696181Z
New count is 25 at approximately 2021-06-17T22:02:55.696448Z
New count is 30 at approximately 2021-06-17T22:02:57.696376Z
Main thread reports counter is 30 at 2021-06-17T22:02:57.702464Z
New count is 35 at approximately 2021-06-17T22:02:59.696243Z
New count is 40 at approximately 2021-06-17T22:03:01.696155Z
Main thread reports counter is 40 at 2021-06-17T22:03:02.707548Z
New count is 45 at approximately 2021-06-17T22:03:03.696134Z
New count is 50 at approximately 2021-06-17T22:03:05.696130Z
New count is 55 at approximately 2021-06-17T22:03:07.695878Z
New count is 60 at approximately 2021-06-17T22:03:09.695790Z
New count is 65 at approximately 2021-06-17T22:03:11.696289Z
New count is 70 at approximately 2021-06-17T22:03:13.696278Z
New count is 75 at approximately 2021-06-17T22:03:15.696278Z
New count is 80 at approximately 2021-06-17T22:03:17.696187Z
New count is 85 at approximately 2021-06-17T22:03:19.696101Z
New count is 90 at approximately 2021-06-17T22:03:21.696009Z
Our demo's `main` method is ending. 2021-06-17T22:03:22.712192Z
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your in-depth explanation of the concepts. I had only one question, will the Atomic Integer work in the my case, as I have shown in my example? Because in my project I can't really get rid of the TimerTask() while still needing a synchronized counter variable. Will Atomic Integers do the job?